# Can I turn a thin steel rod into an electromagnet and have it collect statically charged dust?

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics

[image]

I frequently move dust/salt-like material from one small plastic container to another. I do this with a steel rod about 3x the thickness of a paper clip that has a flattened end.

Sometimes the material is statically charged and either sticks to the sides of the parent container and while scooping it out with the metal rod or when I do get it out sometimes it will blow all over the place. In either case the material I need is either hard to get out of the parent vessel or is lost once I get it out.

Will turning the steel rod into an electromagnet allow me to attract the static material to my steel rod, move it to the new container, and turn it off/drop the material?

Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

No, not with a *magnet*. You need to differentiate between the phenomena of **electricity** and **magnetism** (Technically, they are two sides of the same coin, which is why they are often treated together in a unified framework, dubbed **electromagnetism**, but that equivalence only becomes apparent in the context of special relativity. For most real-world applications, it's two phenomena that interact.)

That being said, *electro*statically charged dust particles carry an excess amount of *electric* charge. That means they are attracted by the opposite electric charge and repelled by the same charge. When you expose electric charges to a magnetic field, they will be deflected when they move within that field by what is known as *Lorenz force*, but they won't be attracted to or repelled from a magnet if they are at rest.

What you need is a rod that is *electrically* charged. You could connect your metal rod to an electrostatic generator (like a [*van de Graaff* generator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_de_Graaff_generator)) with a wire and only touch it with rubber gloves to avoid the charge leaking through your body. But it's probably far easier to try a non-conducting rod, e.g. one made of plastic or glass. You can try rubbing it with a synthetic fabric or a piece of fur. A non-conducting rod will hold the charge for a while even if you touch it with your hands. That being said, you cannot "turn it off" by grounding it like you could with a metal rod, so getting the dust off the rod once it sticks there might be tricky.

Comment: Thank you these are the exact answers I was looking for.

Comment: A question about van de graff generators: can I make one and connect the static producing part to the metal rod or does it need a large bulbous shape to work effectively

Comment: The bulbous shape is there to mitigate discharge losses. Generally speaking the electric field emanating from a charged object will be largest on the parts of its surface that have the strongest curvature, like edges or pointy bits. When the electric field locally exceed the *break-down* strength of roughly $3\times 10^6\,$V/m (exact value depends on humidity etc.), the air will be ionized and electric charge will "leak". That's known as [Corona discharge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corona_discharge). Thus, usually spherical (i.e. low-curvature) domes are used for van de Graaffs.

Comment: I don't think you'd need that high of an electric field though, but it depends on the material of your "dust" particles.

Comment: Ok great thanks. It is a wide variety of substances but usually having a MW between 350 and 1000. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

If the dust doesn't consist of ferromagnetic particles you will probably not be able to attract it effectively to a simple electromagnet. Furthermore, only paramagnetic dust would be attracted, diamagnetic dust would repelled by the inhomogeneous magnetic field.